# Scratch org has no Rollup Summary Limit for Case

Tags: scratch-org, roll-up-summary

Received an error when trying to create a scratch org that we have exceeded the limit of 25 rollup summary fields for Case. We have 31 such fields but Salesforce bumped us up to 35 some time ago. This has not been an issue when creating sandboxes. Also, while Contact Limits and other object limits have a line item for Rollup Summary Limit in a scratch org (with 25 available), there is no line item at all under Case.

I can't find a scratch org configuration setting that might address this.

**Scratch limits**

[image: Sandbox Case Limits]

**Sandbox limits**

[image: Scratch Case Limits]

Comment: Have you tried [Org shape feature](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_shape_enable_org_shape.htm)?

Comment: Not yet. Will look into that. I think you can set limits there, right?

Comment: I don't think you can change limits but the Devhub org limits would be copied as it is

Comment: @Swetha I needed to create a shape, yes! Then, instead of specifying the edition in the scratch definition file, I specified sourceOrg. Please do provide this as the answer, and I'll select it as best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can make use of the [Org shape feature.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_shape_scratch_def.htm) Org shape can mimic your DebHub org's settings, licenses, and features.

Steps as per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_scratch_orgs_shape.htm&release=228&type=5)

> - As an admin, log in to the source org.
> - From Setup, enter Org Shape in the Quick Find box, then select Org Shape.
> - Click Enable Org Shape for Scratch Orgs (Beta).
> - If your source org is different from your Dev Hub org, enter the Dev Hub org ID to the list of allowed Dev Hub orgs.
> - Create a scratch org shape for the source org.
> - Create a scratch org definition file that contains the 15-character source org ID, the only required option.
>
>   {
>   "orgName": "Salesforce",
>   "sourceOrg": "00DB1230400Ifx5"
>   }
> - Create a scratch org.